# How to configure kamailio to forward calls without registration and replace to header

Tags: asterisk, kamailio

I'd like to create public sip gateway to receive calls without registration via uri like a sip:random_login@sip.public.ip

frontend: kamailio 5.0 + mariadb 10.0 (192.168.30.150)
backend: two  asterisk 11 servers to load balance (192.168.30.1,192.168.30.2)

Add into kamailio database my asterisk servers

```
insert into dispatcher (setid,destination,attrs) values (1,"sip:192.168.30.1:5060","weight=50");
insert into dispatcher (setid,destination,attrs) values (2,"sip:192.168.30.2:5060","weight=50");
```

Add to kamailio database new table

```
create table my_trunk (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  alias varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  trunk_id int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  dispatcher_id int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And fill it

```
insert into my_trunk (alias,trunk_id,dispatcher_id) values ('test1',1,1);
insert into my_trunk (alias,trunk_id,dispatcher_id) values ('test2',2,2);
```

Configure kamailio to use sqlops & dispatcher modules

```
# ----------------- setting dispatch module parameters ---------------
loadmodule "dispatcher.so"
modparam("dispatcher", "db_url", "mysql://kamailio:kamailiorw@localhost/kamailio")
modparam("dispatcher", "ds_ping_interval", 30)

loadmodule "sqlops.so"
modparam("sqlops","sqlcon","ca=>mysql://kamailio:kamailiorw@localhost/kamailio")
```

I'd like to receive INVITE request, replace To header and forward it to asterisk server with new header

In kamailio.cfg replace

```
# account only INVITEs
if ( is_method("INVITE") ) {
    setflag(FLT_ACC); # do accounting
}
```

to

```
# account only INVITEs
if ( is_method("INVITE") ) {
    setflag(FLT_ACC); # do accounting
        sql_query("ca", "select dispatcher_id,trunk_id from my_trunk where alias='$tU'","ra");
        $var(ds_force_dst) = $dbr(ra=>[0,0]);
        $var(trunk_id) = $dbr(ra=>[0,1]);

        ds_select_dst($var(ds_force_dst),"4");
        sl_send_reply("100","Trying");
        forward();
        exit();

}
```

Call is forwarded but i don't know how to replace To header to 000-$var(trunk_id) before forward

Answer (score 0):

you can use UAC module that helps to replace,changes SIP URIs.

Suggest : have a look restore mode. maybe useful for you

[UAC module](https://kamailio.org/docs/modules/devel/modules/uac.html#uac.f.uac_replace_to)